# MongoDB user management: not authorized on admin to execute command

Tags: mongodb

I'm writing an app in python that requires some simple user management functions off mongodb. I've hit a snag on "updateUser" with the dreaded
*Updating user failed: not authorized on admin to execute command* and was hoping someone can give me some pointers here. I've set up 2 custom roles in the admin database since I'm using that as the auth db. Here are the roles:

```
db.createRole({
    role: "mydbAdmin", 
    privileges: [], 
    roles: [
        {role: "userAdmin", db: "admin"}, 
        {role: "dbAdmin", db: "admin"}, 
        {role: "readWrite", db: "admin"}, 
        {role: "dbAdmin", db: "mydb"}, 
        {role: "readWrite", db: "mydb"}
    ]});
```

and

```
db.createRole({
    role: "mydbUser", 
    privileges: [{
        resource: {db: "mydb", collection: ""}, 
        actions: ["changeOwnPassword", "changeOwnCustomData"]
    }], 
    roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "mydb"}]});
```

my users are created on the admin database with either "mydbUser" or "mydbAdmin". The "mydbAdmin" can create, grant roles, revoke roles and drop the user as it's suppose to however, when I issue a general "updateUser" to change customData and roles, I get the following error as seen in the pix below:

```
> db.createUser({user: "someuser", pwd: "password", customData: {fullname: "Some"}, roles: ["mydbAdmin"]})
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "someuser",
    "customData" : {
        "fullname" : "Some"
    },
    "roles" : [
        "mydbAdmin"
    ]
}
> db.updateUser("someuser", {customData: {fullname: "Some User"}})
> db.updateUser("someuser", {customData: {fullname: "Some User"}, roles: ["mydbUser"]})
uncaught exception: Error: Updating user failed: not authorized on admin to execute command { updateUser: "someuser", customData: { fullname: "Some User" }, roles: [ "mydbUser" ], writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 600000.0 }, lsid: { id: UUID("c8753cab-e1ce-4ef4-8824-894bbbcd3315") }, $db: "admin" } :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.updateUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1436:11
@(shell):1:1
```

Would really appreciate if someone can give me some pointers as to what I'm doing wrong.

P/S - if I login as the "admin" that has the **AnyDatabase* roles, I can issue that command without errors so clearly I'm missing something in my "mydbAdmin" roles. Any help would really be great as I'm at a loss on how to proceed forward.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots use formatted text see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Replaced screenshot with text

Comment: Would be helpful to tell us in which `db` you execute all these commands and as which **user**.

Comment: As mentioned, all users are created on the 'admin' database. The data is housed in a database called 'mydb'. All user management commands are executed in the 'admin' database. The admin user created using the custom role of "mydbAdmin" is 'tempAdmin'.

Comment: I think it must be `resource: {db: "", collection: ""}, actions: ["changeOwnPassword", "changeOwnCustomData"]` or `resource: {db: "admin", collection: ""}, actions: ["changeOwnPassword", "changeOwnCustomData"]` because the user is created in `admin` database, not `mydb`